# Looking for a free or open-source burner emulator

Tags: windows, dvd, burning, compact-disc, virtual-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual CDR driver](https://superuser.com/questions/50789/virtual-cdr-driver)

I am looking for a free or open-source virtual CD/DVD emulator to run in a Windows environment.

What I want is similar to what SlySoft's [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home) provides, but the emulated drive needs to be a burner of some type. The burner should be able to save disc images (.iso, .ccd, etc) to my harddrive - basically, the same as if I burned the files to a CD-R, and then ripped them back to a disc image.

I have already looked around some and come across 2 - [DVD neXt COPY iTurns](http://www.dvdnextcopyiturns.com/DVDneXtCOPY_iTurns_FREE.html) and [NoteBurner](http://www.noteburner.com/) M4P. Both of these programs create a virtual CD-RW drive, but they are integrated into their product (for burning from iTunes to create mp3 files) and cannot create disc images.

I am currently writing a piece of software that will have the capability to burn disc images onto CDs/DVDs, and I don't want to end up with a 100 coasters while I'm testing my software.

Anyone have any ideas?

> **Related ServerFault queston:**
>
> [Create netbook recovery image without DVD burner (virtual burner?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/19777)

Comment: nothing free or open source for Windows, but check this duplicate question for commercial alternatives: http://superuser.com/questions/50789/virtual-cdr-driver

Comment: Yargh! I swear I triple-checked SuperUser before posting! I don't know how I managed to miss that question - must have hit all the wrong keywords. Thanks Molly

Comment: not a bother, most of these programs are time-trials/evaluations, which might be sufficient for what you need.