# Is there a way to mount a writable disc in a virtual device/drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, iso-image, virtual-drive

Is there a way to mount a writable disc/image on a virtual drive(e.g. daemon tools)? This is for either Windows XP or Windows 7.

The goal being to write a disc directly to an ISO from software that only sees physical and virtual optical devices. Because the discs are temporary so I don't want to waste physical media.

Comment: What about daemon tools doesn't do it for you? Is there something you need that it's lacking?

Comment: As far as I'm aware ImgBurn and Daemon Tools can't emulated burners.  Daemon Tools can mount existing images and create images from files/folders, but you can't use other programs to burn to the virtual drive as though it were a CD-R.

Comment: Pahntom Burner works Great, But I found it does not support Dual Layer DVDs
any Software can burn dual layers virtually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Phantom Burner](http://www.phantombility.com/en/prod/phantomburner/) looks like what you are looking for.

Here is a similar question: [Virtual CDR driver](https://superuser.com/questions/50789/virtual-cdr-driver)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, although I wish the functionality was available in other packages and for less money.

Comment: @Ryan, Glad it worked out for you.  I agree, I wish both read & write ISO files were built into all OSs.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)?

It can create/copy ISOs from real or virtual drives.

Comment: I'm looking for the virtual drive side of things, specifically one that emulates a burner, to create images by "burning" to the virtual device.

Comment: Burning software has the ability to do a "test burn" if that's what you're looking for.

If you're looking to create an ISOs you can use and mount in virtual drives, ImgBurn is a good option.